# how to draw a font's glyphs using svg?

Tags: python, html, svg, fonts, bezier

I'm trying to draw all glyphs of a ttf font file.
I have created a XML file using TTX and parsed it with python to write html file and create SVG. but SVG doesn't support curves with more than two control points so the outlines are not what they should be.

How can I fix this? or is there any other way to draw glyph outlines?

this is the html code I use:

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>font</title>
</head>
  <body>
  <svg width="800" height="800" viewbox="0 0 2000 300" overflow="visible">
<g transform="scale(1,-1)">
<path d="M255 168 C221 168,171 176,152 187 Q102 212,102 272 Q102 331,156 385 C204 433,351 493,414 493 C456 493,503 464,503 434 Q503 393,451 352 C431 336,386 310,362 303 L355 303 Q345 303,339 310 Q333 317,332 328 C332 334,340 348,351 350 Q374 356,412 383 Q456 412,456 434 C456 440,440 446,426 446 C412 446,381 442,358 437 C347 435,323 429,311 425 C242 399,149 316,149 272 C149 240,200 215,244 215 Q293 215,359 229 Q397 237,411 240 Q433 246,465 257 C478 260,502 268,524 276 L534 279 Q544 279,551 272 Q556 264,556 255 C556 248,550 238,541 233 L415 188 Q333 156,281 128 Q209 91,172 51 Q139 16,122 -17 Q107 -51,107 -80 Q107 -129,151 -162 Q193 -191,257 -191 L478 -88 Q484 -81,494 -80 C502 -80,519 -95,519 -106 Q519 -114,512 -121 Q460 -179,389 -211 Q326 -239,261 -239 C176 -239,59 -150,59 -80 C59 -44,96 38,137 83 Q159 107,190 128 C202 138,237 159,255 168" stroke="black" fill="transparent"></path>
  </svg>
    </body>
    </html>
```

[and this is what the glyph outline should look like(from fontLab Studio)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L072U.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

Truetype fonts don't use cubic beziers.  They use quadratic beziers.  So if you see a sequence of points: "on, off, off on", that is not a cubic bezier with two end points and two control points. That is actually a quadratic bezier with two endpoints ("on curve" points), two control points ("off curve" points), and a a dropped middle "on" point.  i.e.:

```
on off (on) off on
```

To reconstruct the middle on point, you just need to find the midpoint between the two "off" control points.

So, for example, that first "cubic" bezier segment:

```
C 221,168, 171,176, 152,187
```

is probably meant to be two quadratic bezier curves:

```
Q 221,168, 191,172
Q 171,176, 152,187
```

Where the new endpoint ("on curve" point) (191,172) = ((221+171) / 2, (168+176) / 2).

*Note that I am guessing here, because I don't know what the original coordinates and flags were in the file.*

If you have a longer sequence of "off curve" points, then you will need to insert extra "on curve" points.  For example at one point, I can see a sequence of four off points, so you will need to insert three on points.

```
on off (on) off (on) off (on) off on
```

Again, in each case, just calculate the point halfway between the two neighbouring off points.

**Update**

So for example, here is the data for a glyph, dumped from a TTF file.

```
    Glyph  54: off = 0x00001E36, len = 210
      numberOfContours:     1
      xMin:                 54
      yMin:                 -12
      xMax:                 502
      yMax:                 712

    EndPoints
    ---------
      0:  44

   Coordinates
   -----------
     0: Rel (   431,   578)  ->  Abs (   431,   578)  on
     1: Rel (   -60,    40)  ->  Abs (   371,   618)
     2: Rel (   -53,     0)  ->  Abs (   318,   618)  on
     3: Rel (   -43,     0)  ->  Abs (   275,   618)
     4: Rel (   -48,   -42)  ->  Abs (   227,   576)
     5: Rel (     0,   -32)  ->  Abs (   227,   544)  on
     6: Rel (     0,   -22)  ->  Abs (   227,   522)
     7: Rel (    31,   -42)  ->  Abs (   258,   480)
     8: Rel (    23,   -20)  ->  Abs (   281,   460)  on
     9: Rel (    77,   -62)  ->  Abs (   358,   398)  on
    10: Rel (    52,   -42)  ->  Abs (   410,   356)
    11: Rel (    59,   -64)  ->  Abs (   469,   292)
    12: Rel (    33,   -72)  ->  Abs (   502,   220)
    13: Rel (     0,   -42)  ->  Abs (   502,   178)  on
    14: Rel (     0,   -44)  ->  Abs (   502,   134)
    15: Rel (   -58,   -90)  ->  Abs (   444,    44)
    16: Rel (  -109,   -56)  ->  Abs (   335,   -12)
    17: Rel (   -75,     0)  ->  Abs (   260,   -12)  on
    18: Rel (   -57,     0)  ->  Abs (   203,   -12)
    19: Rel (  -112,    36)  ->  Abs (    91,    24)
    20: Rel (   -37,    34)  ->  Abs (    54,    58)  on
    21: Rel (    51,    80)  ->  Abs (   105,   138)  on
    22: Rel (    33,   -24)  ->  Abs (   138,   114)
    23: Rel (    69,   -32)  ->  Abs (   207,    82)
    24: Rel (    41,     0)  ->  Abs (   248,    82)  on
    25: Rel (    47,     0)  ->  Abs (   295,    82)
    26: Rel (    62,    51)  ->  Abs (   357,   133)
    27: Rel (     0,    46)  ->  Abs (   357,   179)  on
    28: Rel (     0,    34)  ->  Abs (   357,   213)
    29: Rel (   -42,    57)  ->  Abs (   315,   270)
    30: Rel (   -39,    30)  ->  Abs (   276,   300)  on
    31: Rel (   -69,    51)  ->  Abs (   207,   351)  on
    32: Rel (   -58,    49)  ->  Abs (   149,   400)  on
    33: Rel (   -14,    13)  ->  Abs (   135,   413)
    34: Rel (   -33,    42)  ->  Abs (   102,   455)
    35: Rel (   -20,    53)  ->  Abs (    82,   508)
    36: Rel (     0,    34)  ->  Abs (    82,   542)  on
    37: Rel (     0,    45)  ->  Abs (    82,   587)
    38: Rel (    42,    59)  ->  Abs (   124,   646)
    39: Rel (    41,    32)  ->  Abs (   165,   678)
    40: Rel (    78,    34)  ->  Abs (   243,   712)
    41: Rel (    61,     0)  ->  Abs (   304,   712)  on
    42: Rel (    56,     0)  ->  Abs (   360,   712)
    43: Rel (    95,   -34)  ->  Abs (   455,   678)
    44: Rel (    26,   -27)  ->  Abs (   481,   651)  on
```

I've added "on" to all the points whose flags (not shown here) indicate that they are meant to be on-curve points.

So if we plot the on-curve points (green) and the off-curve points (red) we get this:

```css
.on {
  fill: green;
}

.off {
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<!-- 54,-12 502,712 -->
<svg width="500px" height="500px" viewBox="54 -12 448 724" overflow="visible">
  <g transform="translate(0,712) scale(1,-1)">

    <g class="points">
      <circle cx="431" cy="578" r="5" class="on"/>
      <circle cx="371" cy="618" r="5" class="off"/>
      <circle cx="318" cy="618" r="5" class="on"/>
      <circle cx="275" cy="618" r="5" class="off"/>
      <circle cx="227" cy="576" r="5" class="off"/>
      <circle cx="227" cy="544" r="5" class="on"/>
      <circle cx="227" cy="522" r="5" class="off"/>
      <circle cx="258" cy="480" r="5" class="off"/>
      <circle cx="281" cy="460" r="5" class="on"/>
      <circle cx="358" cy="398" r="5" class="on"/>
      <circle cx="410" cy="356" r="5" class="off"/>
      <circle cx="469" cy="292" r="5" class="off"/>
      <circle cx="502" cy="220" r="5" class="off"/>
      <circle cx="502" cy="178" r="5" class="on"/>
      <circle cx="502" cy="134" r="5" class="off"/>
      <circle cx="444" cy=" 44" r="5" class="off"/>
      <circle cx="335" cy="-12" r="5" class="off"/>
      <circle cx="260" cy="-12" r="5" class="on"/>
      <circle cx="203" cy="-12" r="5" class="off"/>
      <circle cx=" 91" cy=" 24" r="5" class="off"/>
      <circle cx=" 54" cy=" 58" r="5" class="on"/>
      <circle cx="105" cy="138" r="5" class="on"/>
      <circle cx="138" cy="114" r="5" class="off"/>
      <circle cx="207" cy=" 82" r="5" class="off"/>
      <circle cx="248" cy=" 82" r="5" class="on"/>
      <circle cx="295" cy=" 82" r="5" class="off"/>
      <circle cx="357" cy="133" r="5" class="off"/>
      <circle cx="357" cy="179" r="5" class="on"/>
      <circle cx="357" cy="213" r="5" class="off"/>
      <circle cx="315" cy="270" r="5" class="off"/>
      <circle cx="276" cy="300" r="5" class="on"/>
      <circle cx="207" cy="351" r="5" class="on"/>
      <circle cx="149" cy="400" r="5" class="on"/>
      <circle cx="135" cy="413" r="5" class="off"/>
      <circle cx="102" cy="455" r="5" class="off"/>
      <circle cx=" 82" cy="508" r="5" class="off"/>
      <circle cx=" 82" cy="542" r="5" class="on"/>
      <circle cx=" 82" cy="587" r="5" class="off"/>
      <circle cx="124" cy="646" r="5" class="off"/>
      <circle cx="165" cy="678" r="5" class="off"/>
      <circle cx="243" cy="712" r="5" class="off"/>
      <circle cx="304" cy="712" r="5" class="on"/>
      <circle cx="360" cy="712" r="5" class="off"/>
      <circle cx="455" cy="678" r="5" class="off"/>
      <circle cx="481" cy="651" r="5" class="on"/>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Now to the path.  We use quadratic bezier (Q) path commands.  As stated above, if we have two adjacent off-curve points, we insert a calculated on-curve point. The inserted point is just the average of the two off-curve points.  If there are two adjacent on-curve points, we insert a line (L) instead.

That gives us the following result.  The coords in the left column are the original on/off points. And the coords in the right column are the inserted calculated points.

```css
.on {
  fill: green;
}

.off {
  fill: red;
}

path.outline {
  fill: none;
  stroke: grey;
}
```

```html
<!-- 54,-12 502,712 -->
<svg width="500px" height="500px" viewBox="54 -12 448 724" overflow="visible">
  <g transform="translate(0,712) scale(1,-1)">

    <path class="outline"
          d="M 431, 578
             Q 371, 618
               318, 618
             Q 275, 618  251,597
             Q 227, 576
               227, 544
             Q 227, 522  243.5,501
             Q 258, 480
               281, 460
             L 358, 398
             Q 410, 356  439.5,324
             Q 469, 292  485.5,256
             Q 502, 220
               502, 178
             Q 502, 134  473,89
             Q 444,  44  389.5,16
             Q 335, -12
               260, -12
             Q 203, -12  147,6
             Q  91,  24
                54,  58
             L 105, 138
             Q 138, 114  172.5,98
             Q 207,  82
               248,  82
             Q 295,  82  325,107.5
             Q 357, 133
               357, 179
             Q 357, 213  336,240.5
             Q 315, 270
               276, 300
             L 207, 351
             L 149, 400
             Q 135, 413  118.5,434
             Q 102, 455  92,481.5
             Q  82, 508
                82, 542
             Q  82, 587  103,616.5
             Q 124, 646  144.5,662
             Q 165, 678  204,695
             Q 243, 712
               304, 712
             Q 360, 712  407.5,695
             Q 455, 678  468,664.5
             L 481, 651
             Z"/>

    <g class="points">
      <circle cx="431" cy="578" r="5" class="on"/>
      <circle cx="371" cy="618" r="5" class="off"/>
      <circle cx="318" cy="618" r="5" class="on"/>
      <circle cx="275" cy="618" r="5" class="off"/>
      <circle cx="227" cy="576" r="5" class="off"/>
      <circle cx="227" cy="544" r="5" class="on"/>
      <circle cx="227" cy="522" r="5" class="off"/>
      <circle cx="258" cy="480" r="5" class="off"/>
      <circle cx="281" cy="460" r="5" class="on"/>
      <circle cx="358" cy="398" r="5" class="on"/>
      <circle cx="410" cy="356" r="5" class="off"/>
      <circle cx="469" cy="292" r="5" class="off"/>
      <circle cx="502" cy="220" r="5" class="off"/>
      <circle cx="502" cy="178" r="5" class="on"/>
      <circle cx="502" cy="134" r="5" class="off"/>
      <circle cx="444" cy=" 44" r="5" class="off"/>
      <circle cx="335" cy="-12" r="5" class="off"/>
      <circle cx="260" cy="-12" r="5" class="on"/>
      <circle cx="203" cy="-12" r="5" class="off"/>
      <circle cx=" 91" cy=" 24" r="5" class="off"/>
      <circle cx=" 54" cy=" 58" r="5" class="on"/>
      <circle cx="105" cy="138" r="5" class="on"/>
      <circle cx="138" cy="114" r="5" class="off"/>
      <circle cx="207" cy=" 82" r="5" class="off"/>
      <circle cx="248" cy=" 82" r="5" class="on"/>
      <circle cx="295" cy=" 82" r="5" class="off"/>
      <circle cx="357" cy="133" r="5" class="off"/>
      <circle cx="357" cy="179" r="5" class="on"/>
      <circle cx="357" cy="213" r="5" class="off"/>
      <circle cx="315" cy="270" r="5" class="off"/>
      <circle cx="276" cy="300" r="5" class="on"/>
      <circle cx="207" cy="351" r="5" class="on"/>
      <circle cx="149" cy="400" r="5" class="on"/>
      <circle cx="135" cy="413" r="5" class="off"/>
      <circle cx="102" cy="455" r="5" class="off"/>
      <circle cx=" 82" cy="508" r="5" class="off"/>
      <circle cx=" 82" cy="542" r="5" class="on"/>
      <circle cx=" 82" cy="587" r="5" class="off"/>
      <circle cx="124" cy="646" r="5" class="off"/>
      <circle cx="165" cy="678" r="5" class="off"/>
      <circle cx="243" cy="712" r="5" class="off"/>
      <circle cx="304" cy="712" r="5" class="on"/>
      <circle cx="360" cy="712" r="5" class="off"/>
      <circle cx="455" cy="678" r="5" class="off"/>
      <circle cx="481" cy="651" r="5" class="on"/>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

If we just draw the shape in black we get a glyph that looks correct.

```html
<svg width="100px" height="100px" viewBox="54 -12 448 724" overflow="visible">
  <g transform="translate(0,712) scale(1,-1)">

    <path d="M 431, 578
             Q 371, 618
               318, 618
             Q 275, 618  251,597
             Q 227, 576
               227, 544
             Q 227, 522  243.5,501
             Q 258, 480
               281, 460
             L 358, 398
             Q 410, 356  439.5,324
             Q 469, 292  485.5,256
             Q 502, 220
               502, 178
             Q 502, 134  473,89
             Q 444,  44  389.5,16
             Q 335, -12
               260, -12
             Q 203, -12  147,6
             Q  91,  24
                54,  58
             L 105, 138
             Q 138, 114  172.5,98
             Q 207,  82
               248,  82
             Q 295,  82  325,107.5
             Q 357, 133
               357, 179
             Q 357, 213  336,240.5
             Q 315, 270
               276, 300
             L 207, 351
             L 149, 400
             Q 135, 413  118.5,434
             Q 102, 455  92,481.5
             Q  82, 508
                82, 542
             Q  82, 587  103,616.5
             Q 124, 646  144.5,662
             Q 165, 678  204,695
             Q 243, 712
               304, 712
             Q 360, 712  407.5,695
             Q 455, 678  468,664.5
             L 481, 651
             Z"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question but it doesnt work... I tried what you said but the result is not what it should be.

Comment: I believe I got it right.  I'll add an example to my answer to prove it.